# Bootstrap ; making div look like a triangle as attached image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've to make few divs look like as atttached image  i can achieve this using background image for div like this

```
background:url(image.png) no-repeat left top;
```

but i just want to know if there is any other way to do it without using background image , please help me  it its  possible [image]

i have gone through some codes for css triangle but they dont look like this so please help me to do this without images if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproduce your image. Do you want someting like this ?

You'll have to adjust the borders width and element proportions

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVOBZv)

```
#mydiv {
    height: 17px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 51px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1130px solid wheat;
}
```

If you can be more specific about what you need or to reproduce I'll be able to provide you some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of border-bottom, border-left, height. Basically, a triangle with extra height. Or, you can place a triangle on top of a rectangle.

See https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ for examples.